# Input password is not conforming to CSS

Tags: php, html, css, web-deployment-project

I need to style my password input box and
input password is not conforming to my css style sheet. My input text is styled correctly, and it is conforming to my style sheet, however, my type password input is not. In the css file, look for changes of input[type=password]

**CSS Source Code**

```
/* BASIC */
  html {

  }
  body {

    background-image: url(img/logo.PNG);
  }

  a {
    color: #92badd;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 40px 8px 10px 8px; 
    color: #cccccc;
  }

  h2.smallfont {
      font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 1px;
    color: white;
  }

  h4 {
      text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px 1000px 175px;
    color: gold;

  }



  /* STRUCTURE */

  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column; 
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  #formContent {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background: black;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 450px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 30px 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 30px 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-align: center;
  }

  #formFooter {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border-top: 1px solid #dce8f1;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  }



  /* TABS */

  h2.inactive {
    color: #cccccc;
  }

  h2.active {
    color: #0d0d0d;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5fbae9;
  }



  /* FORM TYPOGRAPHY*/

  input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset]  {
    background-color: #56baed;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 80px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0 rgba(95,186,233,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0 rgba(95,186,233,0.4);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 20px 40px 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }

  input[type=button]:hover, input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=reset]:hover  {
    background-color: #39ace7;
  }

  input[type=button]:active, input[type=submit]:active, input[type=reset]:active  {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.95);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    -o-transform: scale(0.95);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.95);
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }

  input[type=text] {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: none;
    color: #0d0d0d;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 85%;
    border: 2px solid #f6f6f6;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  }

  input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5fbae9;
  }

  input[type=text]:placeholder {
    color: #cccccc;
  }

  input[type=password] {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border: none;
    color: #0d0d0d;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 85%;
    border: 2px solid #f6f6f6;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  }

  input[type=password]:focus {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5fbae9;
  }

  input[type=password]:placeholder {
    color: #cccccc;
  }

  /* ANIMATIONS */

  /* Simple CSS3 Fade-in-down Animation */
  .fadeInDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: none;
      transform: none;
    }
  }

  @keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: none;
      transform: none;
    }
  }

  /* Simple CSS3 Fade-in Animation */
  @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
  @-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
  @keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

  .fadeIn {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
  }

  .fadeIn.first {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
  }

  .fadeIn.second {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
  }

  .fadeIn.third {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.8s;
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
  }

  .fadeIn.fourth {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }

  /* Simple CSS3 Fade-in Animation */
  .underlineHover:after {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #56baed;
    content: "";
    transition: width 0.2s;
  }

  .underlineHover:hover {
    color: #0d0d0d;
  }

  .underlineHover:hover:after{
    width: 100%;
  }



  /* OTHERS */

  *:focus {
      outline: none;
  } 

  #icon {
    width:60%;
  }
```

Relevant HTML block...

```
 <!-- Login Form -->

 <form action="loginSystem.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="login" placeholder="username/e-mail">
      <input type="password" id="pass" class="fadeIn third" name="password" placeholder="password">
      <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In">
 </form>
```

Comment: You've used `input[type=button]:active, input[type=submit]:active, input[type=reset]:active`, so you know that you can put multiple selectors together. Why not the same for `input[type=text], input[type=password]` to avoid any chance of one being different from the other?

Comment: This is odd.. the "password" is yet to conform even under the same changes as you wrote about... I am using bootstrap, maybe that is what is interfering? If not, I can make a custom type password class I recon? I don't do web-development, I am an application and robotics dev.

Comment: To give an update* it seems to conform on the phone display. However, it looks awful on the desktop.